# Don't execute the thread when Thread is already running

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a Thread to export date into Excel.

But when i run the Thread for the second time it may not execute..

My code:

```
 if (Thread.CurrentThread == null || Thread.CurrentThread.ThreadState == System.Threading.ThreadState.Stopped)
 {
     new Thread(() =>
     {
         Thread.CurrentThread.Name = "Export to Excel Thread";
         Thread.CurrentThread.IsBackground = true;

         //Code to export to Excel
         // ...
     }).Start();
  }
  else
  {
      MessageBox.Show("Please wait untill the current export is done");
  }
```

I think the problem is that the Thread is not the currentThread in the if statement.

How to solve this?

Comment: How could the current thread ever be null or stopped?  Wouldn't the code... not be executing if that were the case?

Comment: I'd consider using TPL rather than going to this low level.

Comment: Could you explain initial problem? This looks like an incorrect solution to it. Are you trying to prevent second export, until first one has Excel window opened or what?

Comment: @Sinatr When the first Thread is running(Creating a Excel) The Thread may not execute again. Until the Thread is done and the 'export' button is clicked again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would go with the TPL.

You could use something like this:

```
// in your class
private Task _exportTask;

// in your method
if(_exportTask == null || _exportTask.IsCompleted || _exportTask.IsCanceled || _exportTask.IsFaulted)
{
    _exportTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => /* Code to export to Excel */);
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Please wait until the current export is done");
}
```

Explanation why your code doesn't work:
The current thread can never be `null`, because that would mean that there is no thread to execute the code that performs this check. Likewise, it can't be stopped, because that again would mean that the code of your check wouldn't be executed, as the thread is stopped.
`Thread.CurrentThread` always returns the thread that is executing the code that is accessing the value of `Thread.CurrentThread`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but RUN need to be replaced with StartNew(). Worked fine!

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use [BackgroundWorker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class that will handle threading stuff for you. On the second export button click just check [IsBusy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.isbusy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property and do nothing if it's true. Good luck.

Comment: This blog series argues that [BackgroundWorker really is dead at this point and should not be used for new development](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/05/taskrun-vs-backgroundworker-intro.html).

Comment: @CharlesMager, that's Stephen Cleary opinion. `BackgroundWorker` is still viable solution and will be such for as long as `[Obsolete]` is not there.

Comment: I appreciate that, and I agree it still works. I just thought I'd point out there are arguably better alternatives.  I've not used `BackgroundWorker` in years.

Answer (score 0):

> When the first Thread is running(Creating a Excel) The Thread may not execute again. Until the Thread is done and the 'export' button is clicked again!

This could be done really simple by disabling button.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    button1.Enabled = false;
    Task.Run(() =>
    {
        // ... do something here

        Invoke((Action)(() => button1.Enabled = true)); // enable button again
    });
}
```

If export can be called from multiple places (button, menu, automation, scheduler, etc.), then see other answers.